# How to find the gain of Motorola operational amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, gain

How to find the Gain in `dB` for Motorola operational amplifier [MC33282P](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/motorola/MC33284P.pdf) (for T=25°C). The manual has only abstract figures.

Comment: the gain is determined (to a first order) by **HOW** you use the device.  Include a schematic with your circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in the datasheet, and it's not abstract to me (it's just over 120dB):

[image]